# iPhone: Testing application on iphone through Windows

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I have participated in the iPhone Developer Program. I can debug my application through Mac over the iPhone. For some reasons I need to be able to test the same application on another iPhone using Windows. Is there a way to achieve this? How do I deploy the application from Windows? Any pointers will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can drag the provision profile and the app package into itunes and sync.  This is how you can distribute your beta.

Note that the phones will have to be registered(UDID) in the developer program portal.

Comment: See the following tutorials (great for non-technical testers/users, like clients) for instructions on how to get UDID and install ad-hoc:
A) http://www.innerfence.com/howto/find-iphone-unique-device-identifier-udid B)
http://www.innerfence.com/howto/install-iphone-application-ad-hoc-distribution